# How to add file in Solr?

Tags: spring-boot, solr

I use Apache Solr so that I can work with files, I can add regular text fields via Spring, but I don’t know how to add TXT / pdf

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "accounting")
public class Accounting {
@Id
@Field
private String id;
@Field
private File txtFile;
@Field
private String docType;
@Field
private String docTitle;

public Accounting() {
}

public Accounting(String id, String docType, String docTitle) {
    this.id = id;
    this.docTitle = docTitle;
    this.docType = docType;
}
```

here is the problem with the txtFile field

```
   <field name="docTitle" type="strings"/>
  <field name="docType" type="strings"/>
```

These fields that I manually added to schema.xml, I can not figure out how to add a field here that will be responsible for the file, for example, I will add here a txt file, how to do it? Thank you very much. And do I correctly declare the field  `private File txtFile;` in the entity for the file?

Comment: I doubt that you could add the file directly. It is done is by extracting the content of the file and then pushing only the content to a field.

Comment: and what if it is pdf?

Comment: Be it pdf,txt,word,csv...If you are creating an solrDocument object...you have to pass the content of the document to the field...And solr does not store the file at its end....it can store the filePath at its end(if you index the filePath)...

Comment: you can extract the context of pdf/text files using the Tika apis...

Comment: Do I need to read the contents of the document, and then save it? Or is it possible to transfer the document, does he already read the content?

Comment: If you want to achieve it through Java, then yes you need read the content of the document and then create the solrDocument object and save it. You can configure solr with the help of data-config.xml...where in the data-config you can mention the other document details and pass the path of the document to tika ...then tika will extract the content from document and then commits everything to solr

Comment: but I can not use the document solr? get the document, read its contents and save as a separate field?

Comment: Solr (Lucene) doesn't store the PDF file itself. However it can store the text contents of the PDF extracted from the PDF using a text-extractor such as Tika (if indeed the field is marked as stored in the schema). So here you have to read/extract the content and save it solr

Comment: If you want I can share some code for your reference...its not with springboot but it could be a start for you...

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: no, i'm trying to connect solr to postgre

Comment: Ok. But if the above question is answered could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Can I keep in touch with you in another way for other issues?

Comment: sure...drop me a mail at bashettiabhijit@rediffmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr will not store the actual file anywhere. Depending on your config it can store the binary content though. Using the extract request handler Apache Solr which relies on Apache Tika to extract the content from the document.

You can try something like below code. The current code is not using anything from the springboot. Here the content is read from the pdf document and then the data is indexed into solr along with id and filename. I have used the tika apis to extract the content of the pdf.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {

        String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCore1";
        SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        File file = new File("C://Users//abhijitb//Desktop//TestDocument.pdf");
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

        // parsing the document using PDF parser
        PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
        pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

        // getting the content of the document
        //System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :" + handler.toString());

        try {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
            document.addField("id", "123456");
            document.addField("title", fileName);
            document.addField("text", handler.toString());
            solr.add(document);
            solr.commit();
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Once you index the data, it can be verified on the solr admin page by querying for it.
Please find the image for your reference.

[image: Solr Admin Page]